# Изменять контролы в динамически создаваемом фрейме delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

Есть форма, место для создания фреймов и собственно фрейм.
При создании формы фреймы не созданы, они создаются динамически.

```
private
    FFrame: TFrame;
    AFrame: array[0..1] of TFrame;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AFrame[x] := TFrame2.Create(self);
  AFrame[x].Align := alTop;
  AFrame[x].Name:= 't1' + inttostr(x);
  AFrame[x].Tag:= 12345;
  AFrame[x].Parent := ScrollBox1;
  x := x + 1;
end;
```

Фрейм содержит Edit'ы, label, кнопки и т.п.
Не могу понять как передать информацию, например установить надпись на label, при создании фрейма

```
AFrame[x].Label1.Caption := ...
```

не работает

Пробовал через глобальные переменные, но как-то не удобно, т.к. хочу создавать фреймы потоком, вдруг начнут косяки вылазить.
Есть более правильный вариант?

Comment: Делать надо вот такTFrame2(AFrame[0]).Label1.Caption := ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что подход в ответах **Pavel Helmer** и **Igor** имеет место быть, я бы рекомендовал использовать его только для простейших случаев, когда нужно однократно поменять 1-2 свойства в целевом фрейме.

Аргументация:

1. Несмотря на то, что все компоненты, лежащие на фрейме, находятся в `published`-секции, не стоит забывать, что Delphi - это объектно-ориентированный язык. И объект должен представлять собой "черный ящик", контактирующий с внешним миром через **свои** свойства, методы и события. `Label1` - это не свойство и не метод, а переменная, ссылающаяся на внутренний для фрейма объект. И **в идеале** она должна быть недоступна извне.
2. Обращение напрямую к переменным затрудняет модификацию UI и проведение рефакторинга. Сегодня метка, текст которой нужно установить, называется `Label1`, завтра - `lbCaptionLabel`, а послезавтра вместо метки появился `TStaticText` или еще что-нибудь.
3. Работая напрямую с переменными во фрейме, вы лишаете этот фрейм собственного контроля за **своим же** содержимым. Таким образом, если вам будет необходимо, чтобы фрейм произвел какие-либо дополнительные внутренние (и не только) операции при изменении какого-либо внутреннего объекта - придется городить огороды и костыли костылировать.

Таким образом, хоть в данном случае от приведения типа мы никуда не денемся, но при введении своих собственных методов будет облегчено дальнейшее сопровождение этого кода:

```
TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
...
public
  property FrameCaption: string read GetFrameCaption write SetFrameCaption;
end;

function TFrame2.GetFrameCaption: string;
begin
  Result:=Label1.Caption;
end;

procedure TFrame2.SetFrameCaption(const Value: string);
begin
  Label2.Caption:=Result;
  // и вот здесь, помимо установки свойства нашего внутреннего объекта
  // мы вправе делать что угодно, например - запомнить, что содержимое было изменено
  // или изменить цвет шрифта в зависимости от переданного Value
  // или вызвать событие "меня изменили" и т.д.
end;
```

Обращение:

```
TFrame2(AFrame[x]).FrameCaption:='мой текст';
```

**Вариант 2**, если динамически создаваемые фреймы - почти однотипны, т.е. они все содержат единый набор объектов/свойств, которые необходимо менять динамически - создать для фреймов общего предка:

```
type
  TMyCustomFrame = class(TFrame)
  protected
    function GetFrameCaption: string; virtual; abstract;
    procedure SetFrameCaption(const Value: string); virtual; abstract;
  public
    property FrameCaption: string read GetFrameCaption write SetFrameCaption;
  end;
// в другом модуле:
  TMyFrame1 = class(TMyCustomFrame)
  protected
    function GetFrameCaption: string; override;
    procedure SetFrameCaption(const Value: string); override;
  end;
```

В этом случае мы можем объявить массив `AFrame` как

```
AFrame: array[0..1] of TMyCustomFrame;
```

И обращаться уже без всяких приведений типов:

```
AFrame[0].FrameCaption:='мой текст';
```

P.S. Да, на начальном этапе это кажется более сложным, чем обратиться напрямую к Label. Однако, повторюсь, в результате такого подхода мы облегчаем дальнейшее сопровождение кода.

Comment: Весьма и весьма хороший совет, буду пробовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Для обращения к свойствам конкретного объекта класса `TFrame2`, надо обращаться именно к нему, произведя приведение типа, вот так:

```
TFrame2(AFrame[x]).Label1.Caption := ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Заведите локальную переменную типа `TFrame2`, и все `published`/`public` члены класса станут видны:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  newFrame: TFrame2;
begin
  newFrame := TFrame2.Create(self);
  newFrame.Align := alTop;
  newFrame.Name:= 't1' + inttostr(x);
  newFrame.Tag:= 12345;
  newFrame.Parent := ScrollBox1;
  newFrame.Label1.Caption := ...
  x := x + 1;
  AFrame[x] := newFrame;
end;
```